# CKEditor 3.6.4 not working on Samsung S2, S3

Tags: android, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor 3.6.4 on a project and I just noticed when testing on samsung galaxy s2 and samsung galaxy s3 that editor does not load. This also happens on the demo page http://ckeditor.com/demo. Editor does appear here as I am trying this on the S2 & S3, though it acts a little strange.

Just wondering if other people have had this issue or is there something I need to do to make it work on the S2 and S3.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Still ckeditor team is working on, to make ckeditor compatible with android browsers. It work almost fine with iphone browser. Read at below Url; http://ckeditor.com/support/faq/features#question9

In your code you can detect the browser type. And use basic buttons of the toolbar. It may work.

Comment: One year later, April 2014, CKEditor has reached v.4.3.4 and they are still writing "the best web text editor for everyone" in big letters on their homepage. Cannot believe it. Still does NOT work on Android phones.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes CKEditor is not able to detect browser and end up missing it from compatible browsers list.

Add following code and check again if it works.

CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;